# How do I override base classes field functionality?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Well, I have `BaseModel`

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Also i have model `Update`

```
public class Update : BaseModel
{
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

which is derived from `BaseModel`
In `BaseModel` `Id` field is not incremented, but for `Update` model I need `Id` with `Identity`.

Can I add new field to `Update` like `UpdateId` which will be incremented, but remove field `Id`?

---

Is it possible solution? :

How about just declare models in next way

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Update : BaseModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

`Id` in `Update` will override `Id` in `BaseModel`

Comment: Are there any entities that inherit from `BaseModel` that do not want `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, yes, I have more than 3 entities, that should be without identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following technique (heavily used in Windows Forms controls to apply different attributes to the one and the same property):

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

public class Update : BaseModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override int Id { get { return base.Id; } set { base.Id = value; } }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>well you can hide the Id from the `BaseModel` in the `UpdateModel`</s>

 
    <s>`public class UpdateModel : BaseModel
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public new int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    }`</s>

### **EDIT**

Based on the comments the above solution is totally wrong from the programmatic point of view because the backing field `Id` if you cast any entity derived from `UpdateModel` to `BaseModel` will be empty although it will compile and gives the desired result.

check the below solution

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
public class UpdateEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}

public class Entity1 : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Entity2 : UpdateEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}

public abstract class UpdateEntityTypeConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T : UpdateEntity
{
    public UpdateEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class Entity1Configuration : BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<Entity1>
{
    public Entity1Configuration()
        : base()
    {
        Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
public class Entity2Configuration : UpdateEntityTypeConfiguration<Entity2>
{
    public Entity2Configuration()
        : base()
    {
        Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var typesToRegister = from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                              where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace) &&
                                    type.BaseType != null &&
                                    type.BaseType.IsGenericType
                              let genericType = type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                              where genericType == typeof(BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<>) || genericType == typeof(UpdateEntityTypeConfiguration<>)
                              let genericArgument = type.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault()
                              where genericArgument != null && genericArgument.BaseType != null &&
                              (genericArgument.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity) || genericArgument.BaseType == typeof(UpdateEntity))
                              select type;

        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keyword `new` - is it required here?

Comment: just to hide the inhereted Id property from the BaseModel ... [Check This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)

Comment: @demo This is incorrect "solution". The `UpdateModel' class will have 2 Id properties (and backing fields), and the property get/set via base class cast will be different from the ones get/set via the derived class. Which can lead to strange bugs and behaviors. It's just a wrong design.

Comment: @IvanStoev, well I have generate table from this entity and it created only one column with field `Id`

Comment: @demo Table is ok, The memory representation is not. Anyway, it's up to you. I'm not saying you should pick mine - Yacoub Massad solution is probably better. This one is worst, I would never use such in production code.

Comment: @IvanStoev ... I do accept that mine is the worst solution because the backing fields if you cast the entity to BaseModel you will find that the Id property empty.... I do apologize for that incorrect solution. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your  context class (that inherits from `DbContext`), you can override the settings for the `Update` entity by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Update>()
        .Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

}
```

Quoting from [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx):

> You can further configure your model by using data annotations or the fluent API. Precedence is given to configuration through the fluent API followed by data annotations and then conventions.

This means that you can override data annotation configuration with the fluent API (via `OnModelCreating`).